# how to trim everything between @ and space character in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a column which I want to clean based on a regex function.

Here is the sample

```
select "@meow I don't want to go in!!" as ip
union all
select "@okay232 u better take @carl .." as ip
union all
select "okay okay, I am going with @meow." as ip
```

I want to delete all of the words that have @ associated with it. How can I do this in bigquery?

I tried with

```
regexp_replace(ip,"\\@(.*?[ ]) ","") as output
```

but the last example still retains `@meow`

```
output  
I don't want to go in!!
u better take ..
okay okay, I am going with @meow
```

NOTE -  if the last word in the string has an `@` with it, I want to remove that word too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below will work

```
select *, trim(regexp_replace(ip, r'@[^\s]*', '')) cleaned
from `project.dataset.table`
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]